# Armature CTRL on the right side doesn't work how it does on the left

Tags: rigging

Still trying to work on this armature and all the problems I've been having started when I Symmetrized my left side of bones to the right. My left lip CTRL bone works perfectly as it should but the right one deforms the bones incorrectly to the left side.
Here's the file
I'm unsure if it has to do with the axis or not
https://workupload.com/file/9y6VVhdzpkf

Comment: Hello, so was my answer to your previous question correct?

Comment: Yes thank you very much!

Comment: It's very hard to guess what bone doesn't work, maybe remove all the bones except the important ones

Comment: can you tell the name of bone ?